# How to use Google One Tap login with django-allauth?

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, google-authentication, django-allauth

Google One Tap login doesn't use an OAuth flow. My question is how to integrate it into a django app that uses allauth for authentication?

I found a tutorial through which you can get the basic details like email, name from the one tap login https://developers.onelogin.com/quickstart/google-ontap-with-onelogin

How does one integrate it to complete the login?

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate it with this views:

```
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.google.views import GoogleOAuth2Adapter
from rest_auth.registration.views import SocialLoginView

from rest_auth.registration.serializers import SocialLoginSerializer


class GoogleLogin(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = GoogleOAuth2Adapter
    serializer_class = SocialLoginSerializer

    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
        kwargs['context'] = self.get_serializer_context()
        return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)
```

and add your google auth key in your settings.py file like this:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        "APP": {
            "client_id": env.str("GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID", ""),
            "secret": env.str("GOOGLE_SECRET_KEY", ""),
        },
    },
}
```

Important: Above views models expected a payload in POST method and those you will found from oauth2 response as soon as a user is authenticated by Google.

I dont know what is your frontend, but you can find related SDK for the frontend, just use the response data to send the payload, that's enough. things are more easier than your thought